# Compare six arrays at once

Tags: objective-c, arrays, cocoa-touch, ios

I have six arrays, and I want to compare all those arrays at the same time. Can someone please suggest a solution for this?

Comment: Depending on what are you trying to do, there might be easier solution.

Answer (score 5):

> isEqualToArray: Compares the receiving
>   array to another array.
>
> - (BOOL)isEqualToArray:(NSArray *)otherArray Parameters otherArray An array. Return Value YES if the
>     contents of otherArray are equal to
>     the contents of the receiving array,
>     otherwise NO.
>
> Discussion Two arrays have equal
>   contents if they each hold the same
>   number of objects and objects at a
>   given index in each array satisfy the
>   isEqual: test.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Declared In NSArray.h

From [NSArray Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/NSArray.html)