# How to compare an array with other array of items whether they are equal in iPhone sdk

Tags: iphone, objective-c

HI,

In my program I have to display six different items in six coloumns.
 In that I display second column items by comparing with items in first column and
 display if and only if there are not equal.

For third column display I have to compare with first and second column  and so on ..

like this For sixth column I have to compare with the previous 5 columns.

Can anyone suggest the sample code to do this in a simple manner.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Compare six arrays at once](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6108781/compare-six-arrays-at-once)

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
if([arr1 isEqualToArray:arr2])
{
    NSLog(@"both are equal....");
}
```

to check if two arrays are equal